# How to apply Entity Framework migration scripts to restore a database in an existing ASP.NET Core Web application

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, migration

I have an existing ASP.NET Core Angular Web application with the usual flairs. It comes with set of migration scripts (e.g. `20151227555555_AddIdentity.cs`, `20161227444444_AddCoreEntities.cs` etc) in a `Migration/` code folder, each has `Up`, `Down`, and `BuildTargetModel` methods.

then there is another folder called `MigrationScript` that contains the equivalent of table creation SQL scripts (straight-up `CREATE TABLE`...) for the various database entities.

I am used to running database management and recreation/restore via a database project that I can "`publish`". I am new to the EF Migration way of doing it, so how do I run those migration C# scripts to create the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the C# migration scripts already contains `Up()` and `Down()` methods means they are ready to be applied. (Note: usually the `Up` and `Down` methods are created by the `Add-Migration migrationname` command).

Here is how to apply the C# entity framework migration scripts in an existing project:

1. Create the empty database with the correct database name. The database name is usually defined in the `aspsettings.json` file under `ConnectionStrings` group. Open Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, create an empty database with the correct name.
2. In Visual Studio Solution Explorer, right-mouse click on the project that contains the `Migration` folder (where the C# migration scripts are located), choose `Manage NuGet Packages...` and look under `Installed` tab to see if `Microsoft.EntityFrameWorkCore.Tools` package is installed, if not go ahead install it. Because that is the package that contains the EF migration commands, i.e. `Add-Migration`, `Update-Database` etc
3. With the `Microsoft.EntityFrameWorkCore.Tools` package installed in the project that contains the `Migration` folder, open the `Package Manager Console` via `Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console` menu options.
4. At the `Package Manager Console` prompt, type the command `Update-Database`, then all of the migration scripts will be applied and the tables created in the local SQL Server database created in step 1.